# Input mismatch int

Tags: java

I have a this small code:

```
    Scanner vloz = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cisla = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10){
            try {
                System.out.println("Vloz cislo " + i + ":");
                int cislo = Integer.parseInt(vloz.nextLine());
                 ++i;
                cisla = cisla + cislo;
                }
            catch(InputMismatchException exception){
                System.out.println("Nevlozil si cislo!");
                }
            }
    float priemer = cisla / i;
    System.out.println("Priemer cisel je " + priemer + ".");
    }   
}
```

but always when I run it and type other charakters then int, program crash and did not run through "catch".
The goal of the program is when the other then int is typed show error message, do not add to int i and give another option to the user to add the intenger.

Comment: Are you sure the exception being thrown is an `InputMismatchException` and not some other exception type, say, `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: ...... my bad.... very thank you for yor effort.... I did not catch it... now runnin smoothly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be catching a [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) rather than an [`InputMismatchException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner vloz = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cisla = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10){
      try {
        System.out.print("Vloz cislo " + i + ":");
        int cislo = Integer.parseInt(vloz.nextLine());
        i++;
        cisla = cisla + cislo;
      } catch(NumberFormatException exception) {
        System.out.println("Nevlozil si cislo!");
      }
    }
    float priemer = cisla / i;
    System.out.println("Priemer cisel je " + priemer + ".");
  }   
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/EwjR/0)

Answer (score 0):

You catch the wrong exception. The method [`parseInt(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) throws a `NumberFormatException` **not** a `InputMismatchException`. Change your catch clause to `catch(NumberFormatException exception)`.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;
public class demo{

```
public static void main (String []args ){

    Scanner vloz = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cisla = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10){
            try {
                System.out.println("Vloz cislo " + i + ":");
                int cislo = Integer.parseInt(vloz.nextLine());
                 ++i;
                cisla = cisla + cislo;
                }
            catch(InputMismatchException exception){
                System.out.println("Nevlozil si cislo!");
                }
            }
    float priemer = cisla / i;
    System.out.println("Priemer cisel je " + priemer + ".");

}
```

}

I'm not sure why it crashed but this code works. I think you may have forgotten to import.java.*;